# How to load 100 urls as http request in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have 100 urls/tickers, and I want to load them in test plan(JMeter) as HTTP Request and I want to check the response(text, code) of each URL.

My goal is to check each URL/ticker is active or not and data is loaded or not.

I don't care about load time but I do care about response time. How to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Add Thread Group. Configure it as follows:
  Number of Threads: whatever you like `Loop Count: tick Forever or put -1`
- Add CSV Data Set Config as a child of the Thread Group and configure it like: Filename: full path to the file with URLs
  Variable names: whatever you like, i.e. ${url}
  Recycle on EOF: False
  Stop thread on EOF: True
- Add HTTP Request sampler after the CSV Data Set Config and configure it as:

  Name: ${url}
  Path: ${url} - the URL from CSV file
- Use Response Assertion and Duration Assertion to check data and response time
- In response assertion check pattern matching rule as "Contains" and create a variable in "pattern to test"  like : `${verify}.`
  Now You should have a column name as Verify which contains the expected result of URLs in your .CSV file
- Add Listener `"View result tree"` to check the response and pass/fail on the basis of expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to **Create a Performance Test** Plan in Jmeter:

1. Start JMeter
2. Select Test Plan on the tree
3. **Add Thread Group**
4. Right click on the **Test Plan and add a new thread group**:

   - Add
   - Threads (Users)
   - Thread Group
5. In **Thread Group control panel**, enter Thread Properties:

   - **Number of Threads: 100 (Number of users connects to target website: 100)** *[Exactly this step will load 100 users for you Sameer]*
   - Loop Count: 10 (Number of time to execute testing)
   - Ramp-Up Period: 100
6. Add JMeter elements by right-clicking on the Thread Group and selecting:

   - Add
   - Config Element
   - HTTP Request Defaults
7. In the HTTP Request Defaults control panel, enter the Website name under test (http://www.google.com)
8. **HTTP Request by right-click on Thread Group** and select:

   - Add
   - Sampler
   - HTTP Request
9. In HTTP Request Control Panel, the **Path field** indicates which URL request you want to send to Google server

   10. **For example**, if you enter "calendar" in Path field. JMeter will create the URL request http://www.google.com/calendar  to Google server
   11. In this test, you keep the Path field blank to make JMeter create the URL request http://www.google.com to Google server
   12. **Run Test and get the test result**

       - Press Run button (Ctrl + R) on Toolbar to start the testing process.

This is open list > Pls add steps if you observed different than above. It helps everyone here!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest designing your Test Plan as follows:

1. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). Configure it as follows:

   - Number of Threads: whatever you like
   - Loop Count: tick `Forever` or put `-1`
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) as a child of the Thread Group and configure it like:

   - Filename: full path to the file with URLs
   - Variable names: whatever you like, i.e. `${url}`
   - Recycle on EOF: `False`
   - Stop thread on EOF: `True`
3. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler after the CSV Data Set Config and configure it as:

   - Name: `${url}` - make sampler name the same as URL so you could distinguish them in the reports
   - Path: `${url}` - the URL from CSV file
4. Use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) to check data and response time

Comment: thanks for the answer, i need assertion on each url how to acheive this?

Comment: Different assertion for each URL?

Comment: yes, responce asserion by size